# Symfony2 change form labels based on url

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have several versions of a form that exist.  The form has all the same questions but the labels for the form are different based on who is filling it out (1st vs 3rd person).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach accomplishing this.  I know I could create a different set of templates however the form is rather large and it would be nice to change it on the fly.

I ask because I find that Symfony's tool bag is large and I am afraid I am overlooking something.  As of right now the only way I see possible is using an [Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try looking at the Symfony Forms tutorial.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well enough.  The point is to have multiple labels for all fields in a form.  A label is simple but changing the label based on a different perspective is a little different.

Comment: What do you mean by perspective? Give me a use case for what you are looking for.

Comment: @RichardChristensen As I state in the questions the labels will change based on who is filling it out (perspective), 1st person or 3rd person.  Two sets of labels are needed and possibly a third.

Comment: It may be easier to think of it in terms of a form that a teacher and a student both have access to.  The questions are going be slightly different to make it more understandable to each party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your talking strictly about the presentation layer. I would investigate using translations for this. Having multiple form classes or a bunch of logic in your controller will be frustrating. You mentioned first and third person. How do you determine if a user is in one of those groups? Perhaps you create a wrapper service for the translation component which checks your requirements and delegates accordingly. It seems like all your doing is speaking another language.

Your main issue is determining whom is first person and whom is third person. Does that change throughout the session? If not do that in your authentication process ( a security voter could work for the determination ) or/and store it in the session if it does change. Override the translation service to use your wrapper to make a decision on what translation to use.

By no means am I saying it's easy but I think using the translation component, authentication as a director and the service container you can get what you want and not muddle your code base.

Comment: This is a really cool idea!  I'll post my result when I figure it out but I am pretty sure I will head in this direction.  Really solid suggestion!

Comment: do you know if there is a way to map a translation directly to an entity or a form type so that based on naming convention of the variable it will use the translation as the `label`?  It looks like the only way to complete this as of right now is to explicitly request the tag inside the translation.

Comment: Never mind this thing is pretty cool.  You can just put the tag name in the label and it works!  I love when its easy!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. use [Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes) To create 2 form classes, and in your controller, you set the appropriate form class to a twig variable then in your template you render

```

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.field1) }}
    {{ form_row(form.field2) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

```

Doing it this way allows you to define the form that displays depending on who is viewing it. You can then define in your services config the method to call from your controller to set this class before the Controller action is called.

Comment: This is a heavy way to do it.  You can use event listeners to accomplish the same thing or even an options resolver.  I was looking to see if there are any tools that may be unique to Symfony that I didn't know about to handle this odd scenario.  I think I might have found something with translations.  I will post if I figure it out.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: What are your thoughts on maybe using form themes to try to accomplish the task?